# Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1) when assigning a name to a string

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am newer to Fortran and the assignment is to print what is on the code.

```
program AssignmentOne
    !Nik Wrye
    !CDS-251-001
    !Assignment #1
    !September 2, 2021
    
    !This program is to print out my full name, email address, course number, 
    !'Assignment 1', and the due date on the terminal screen.
    
    implicit none
    
    !I will now declare the variables with a delimiter
    character(len=42):: String1, String2, String3, String4, String5
    
    String1 = Full name: Nikolas Wrye
    String2 = Email address: redacted@redacted.edu
    String3 = Course number: CDS-251-001
    String4 = Assignment One
    String5 = Due date: September 2nd, 2021
    
    !Telling the terminal what to do with values
        
    print*, String1
    print*, String2
    print*, String3
    print*, String4
    print*, String5
    
    !The end
end program AssignmentOne
```

It keeps giving me the error:

```
$ gfortran AssignmentOne.f95 
AssignmentOne.f95:15:2: 
15 | String1 = Full name: Nikolas Wrye 
 1 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. It is important to write a title, that somehow describes your actual problem. The title you used could really be about anything. If the system tells you, that such a title already exist, you *really* should read the existing questions first. Please always search for questions with the same error message first before asking a new question.\

Comment: Update the error is: $ gfortran AssignmentOne.f95
AssignmentOne.f95:15:2:

   15 |         String1 = Full name: Nikolas Wrye
      |         1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to include any updates. Simply rewrite the existing content.

Comment: The error message in your question doesn't match the code there. However, "I will now declare the variables with a delimiter" doesn't match your code either: you need to use delimiters when using character constants.

Comment: That means: `String1 = "Full name: Nikolas Wrye"`

Comment: I updated the code, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Alright, I updated the code. Not getting that error anymore, I have experience in Java, just trying to get used to the syntax haha. Really facepalming hard right now.